Why is the first row failing to change color? (Purpose: Script to change the color of links specifically on script run/onOpen)
This is a script that I'm workshopping to change the colors of any given data range's links. It's meant to re-analyze on open so that there aren't any "slips" of unstyled links where someone can see.
For now, I'm working on a version that styles all the text based on specified ranges. The first row  has some cells that's merged, but afaik, that's not a problem, since it works on the next row that also has some merged cells.
I'll try to describe some things that may or may not contribute to the problem, so looking at the spreadsheet might not be necessary, though I do have a copy of the current version available here. You're gonna have to approve importing some ranges if you make copies, but otherwise you should have no issues ("jump to" links, however, will be broken.)
Here is also the code, in case looking at it's all you need. Code also spoilered below (since, apparently, I need it.)
Guesses on what might be problematic:

The first row is meant to have white text
The links in the first 2 rows are meant to override the "normal" color
The original array was sliced and concatenated to the array that sets the text color. Without those 2 arrays (and other code that deletes the first 2 rows of the original text color array), the text color would just be normal text black and link blue.
The top colors array is in a separate loop than the initial text color setting loop. The top colors array, afaik, still should work because 1. 2. of top colors is setting the color perfectly.
There was mixed usage of rich text value and font Color. RTF "found" the links, font color changed the... font's color.
The raw data from getting the data range is what was edited. I didn't use display value. That, I plan to use for a variation of this script.

Tried:
As you can see from the code, a lot of logs to the console were made. I tried workshopping as much as possible. I tried seeing if the length of the arrays were okay, and made sure the dimensions lined up. That seems fine. Each subarray is 15 elements long. I made sure the first and second lines (the "problem areas") both have the same dimensions and colors.
I was having issues doing some things, like making a true/false array for the links and making a loop to check all the text. I did those in roundabout ways just so I could "read" what was going on and not get confused by someone else's code. I made 2 separate loops to make "if/else" blocks that were "legible" to me.
A lot of the old variations of code were "lost" because I didn't record them in the draft, to make it legible. But, for things like the loops and the "if/else" blocks had several drafts before I ended up with something that worked.
Code:
Looks like you just get your page stretched.
/* @OnlyCurrentDoc */
/**
* A funtion to style links.

@param: {string} arg1 - The sheet in this workbook that's meant to be styled.
@param: {string} arg2 - Hex code expressing the desired color for just the links.
@param: {string} arg3 - Hex code expressing the desired color for the "body" of the specified sheet.
@param: {string} arg4 - Hex code expressing the desired color for the first row's text.
@param: {string} arg5 - Hex code expressing the desired color for the second row's text.

**/
function styleLinks(arg1="Neopets Blueprints Wishlist",arg2="#ffffff",arg3="#000000",arg4="#ffffff",arg5="#0b5394") {
var sheet = SS.getSheetByName("Neopets Blueprint Wishlist" || arg1);
var data1 = sheet.getDataRange();
var dataWord1 = data1.getDisplayValues();
var linkColor = '#3c78d8' || arg2;
//textColor1 is the "normal", general text color.
var textColor1 = '#000000' || arg3;
//textColor2 is the first row color.
var textColor2 = '#ffffff' || arg4;
//textColor3 is the second row color.
var textColor3 = '#0b5394' || arg5;
var data1LC = sheet.getLastColumn();
var data1LR = sheet.getLastRow();
var links1 = [];

        var inherit1 = data1.getRichTextValue();
        var inheritStyle = inherit1.getTextStyle();
        var inheritColor = inheritStyle.getForegroundColorObject();



var textColors = [];
//console.log(dataWord1.length);
//console.log(data1LC);
//console.log(data1LR);
//console.log(dataWord1[1]);
//console.log(dataWord1)
//console.log(dataWords1.length);
//console.log(dataWord1[2]);

//Below makes array of the Display Values.
var dataWords1a = dataWord1.join().split(',');
//Below makes an array of words from the previous array (Currently unused, meant for another draft of the code)
//var dataWords1b = dataWords1a.join().split(" ");

//dataWord1 is what the individual cells show (on each row), the outer array broken up by columns. 
//console.log(dataWord1);
//console.log(dataWord1[1]);

var dataRTVLinks = data1.getRichTextValues().map(r => r.map(c => {
    const link = c.getLinkUrl();
    return link;
}));

function linkBool(item) {
  if(item === null) { return false } else { return true };
}

//console.log(dataRTVLinks[1]);
//console.log(dataRTVLinks[5]);


let dataLinksBool = dataRTVLinks.map(r => r.map(linkBool));
var links2Rows = dataLinksBool.slice(0,2);
//console.log(links2Rows);
//console.log(dataLinksBool[1]);
//console.log(dataWord1[1]);

for (let i = 0; i < dataLinksBool.length; i++) {
textColors[i] = [];
for (let j = 0; j < data1LC; j++)
{if(dataLinksBool[i][j] == true){
  textColors[i][j]= linkColor} else {textColors[i][j] = textColor1;}
  }
}

//console.log(textColors.length);
//console.log(textColors[0].length);
//console.log(textColors[2].length);
//console.log(textColors[15].length);

var topColors = [];
for (let k=0; k < links2Rows.length; k++) {
topColors[k] = [];
for (let l = 0; l < data1LC; l++) {
  if(links2Rows[k][l] == true) {
    topColors[k][l] = linkColor} 
    else if (links2Rows[k][l] == false && k < 1) {
      topColors[k][l] = textColor2 } else 
      {topColors[k][l] = textColor3 }
}

}
console.log(topColors);
console.log(topColors[0].length);

topColors.flat();

let topArr1 = topColors.splice(0, 1).flat();
let topArr2 = topColors.splice(0, 1).flat();

//console.log("topArr1:");
//console.log(topArr1);
//console.log("topArr2:");
//console.log(topArr2);

textColors.splice(0,2,topArr1,topArr2);

//console.log(textColors[1]);

//data1.setFontColors(textColors);

}

//console.log(dataLinksBool[1]);
//console.log(dataLinksBool[5]);

Edit: I'm sorry that I forgot to mention specifics on the code. The text in certain cells would change color to hex strings specified in the formula.
The input would be hex codes that correlate to regions (2 header rows,  all the page's links and the rest of the sheet.) It would generate an array of colors the same dimensions as the sheet's data, then apply the array with the textColor() method.

Learn how to paste  and - format code

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

@Tanaike Yes, of course. The main purpose of this script is to color text based on parameters typed into the function. The locations of the colors are based on what my particular "style" is for a specific sheet. I wanted to make this to find and color links anywhere on the page.
The first 2 rows are supposed to have white text and blue text, respectively, unless the particular cell has a link (all the links have the same color.) The method I chose to place the colors is with an array.
Though the code is "placing" the colors in the right place, applying the code works everywhere but row 1

Thank you for explaining the purpose of the script; that is useful. The other information that we need is sample input and output situations you expect.

@Tedinoz I'm sorry, I forgot to add that part. The input would be strings expressed as hex codes (for parameters that effect certain regions of the page.) The output would be the relevant sheet in a workbook change formatting; cells in the specified regions would have the text's original color change to the specified colors.

The input would be I'm sorry to be pedantic but it's best to clear this up. The expectation is that you would edit the question to include actual input and output data; this might in the form of a spreadsheet and/or markdown tables (but NOT as images).

No, it's welcome to hear what's best to make helping me in any way easier. I added the exact specifications to the bottom post, edited the script to include the parameter descriptions, and the spreadsheet link is already there; it's an exact copy of the master document with the current code. It's in paragraph 3 (labeled "here.") @Tedinoz

You're gonna have to approve importing some ranges if you make copies, but otherwise you should have no issues ("jump to" links, however, will be broken.) No: on copying cellA3=#REF! (You don't have permissions to access that spreadsheet). Anyway, the spreadsheet (as-is) is not helpful. No doubt you have a vivid understanding of your scenario but for users the scenario is vague with no examples of actual data, results of the script as written, or expected outcome. Refer Minimal, Reproducible Example.
